# Spring AMPQ multiple consumers vs higher prefetch value

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Even after reading plenty of SO questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015650/spring-amqp-single-consumer-parallelism-with-prefetch),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699727/what-is-the-difference-between-prefetch-count-vs-no-ack-in-rabbitmq)) and articles, It is unclear on which is the better option to set for consumers. Multiple consumers or a higher prefetch value?

From what I understand, when it comes to `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory`, <del>as it was designed initially to have only one thread per connection</del> it was designed to address a limitation that the amqp-client only had one thread per connection, does that mean that setting multiple consumers won't make much difference as there is only one thread that actually consumes from rabbit and than hands it off to the multiple consumers (threads)?
Or there are actually several consumers consuming at the same time?

So what is the best practice when it comes to spring implementation of rabbit concerning prefetch/consumers? When should one be used over the other? And should I switch to this new `DirectRabbitListenerContainerFactory`? Is it 'better' or just depends on the use case?

Some downsides I see when it comes to high prefetch is that maybe it can cause memory issues if an app consumes more messages that it can hold in the buffer? (haven't actually tested this yet, tbh)

And when it comes to multiple consumers, I see the downside of having more file descriptors opened on OS level and I saw [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/05/11/some-queuing-theory-throughput-latency-and-bandwidth/) article about that each consumer actually pings rabbit for each ack and this making it slower.

FYI, if it is relevant, I usually have my config set up like this:

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
final CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(server);
connectionFactory.setUsername(username);
connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(virtualHost);
connectionFactory.setRequestedHeartBeat(requestedHeartBeat);
return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
    AmqpAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    admin.declareQueue(getRabbitQueue());
    return admin;
}

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
final SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
factory.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrency);
factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(maxConcurrency);
factory.setPrefetchCount(prefetch);
factory.setMissingQueuesFatal(false);
return factory;
}

@Bean
public Queue getRabbitQueue() {
final Map<String, Object> p = new HashMap<String, Object>();
p.put("x-max-priority", 10);
return new Queue(queueName, true, false, false, p);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; the SMLC wasn't "designed for one thread per connection" it was designed to address a limitation that the amqp-client only had one thread per connection so that thread hands off to consumer threads via an in-memory queue; that is no longer the case. The client is multi-threaded and there is one dedicated thread per consumer.

Having multiple consumers (increasing the concurrency) is completely effective (and was, even with the older client).

Prefetch is really to reduce network chatter and improve overall throughput. Whether you need to increase concurrency really is orthogonal to prefetch. You would typically increase concurrency if (a) your listener is relatively slow to process each message and (b) strict message ordering is not important.

The `DirectListenerContainer` was introduced to provide a different threading model, where the listener is invoked directly on the amqp-client thread.

The reasons for choosing one container over the other is described in [Choosing a Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#choose-container).

> The following features are available with the SMLC, but not the DMLC:
>
> - `txSize` - with the SMLC, you can set this to control how many messages are delivered in a transaction and/or to reduce the number of acks, but it may cause the number of duplicate deliveries to increase after a failure. (The DMLC does have mesagesPerAck which can be used to reduce the acks, the same as with txSize and the SMLC, but it can’t be used with transactions - each message is delivered and ack’d in a separate transaction).
> - `maxConcurrentConsumers` and consumer scaling intervals/triggers - there is no auto-scaling in the DMLC; it does, however, allow you to programmatically change the consumersPerQueue property and the consumers will be adjusted accordingly.
>
> However, the DMLC has the following benefits over the SMLC:
>
> - Adding and removing queues at runtime is more efficient; with the SMLC, the entire consumer thread is restarted (all consumers canceled and re-created); with the DMLC, unaffected consumers are not canceled.
> - The context switch between the RabbitMQ Client thread and the consumer thread is avoided.
> - Threads are shared across consumers rather than having a dedicated thread for each consumer in the SMLC. However, see the IMPORTANT note about the connection factory configuration in the section called “Threading and Asynchronous Consumers”.

Comment: Thanks for making it clearer. Can I use a combination of the two? Having multiple consumers with a higher prefetch value meaning that each consumer will fetch x messages? Or it is not cumulative?

Comment: Yes you can use both. Each consumer will get up to prefetch messages. Prefetch is essentially the number of unacknowledged messages allowed by the broker at the consumer; it is set by the consumer before it issues a `basicConsume` operation. With low message rates, a too-high prefetch might cause an imbalance (one idle consumer while the other has all the available messages in its prefetch buffer). So you need to tune the prefetch based on your situation.